# Can we do something about this good question left unanswered?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[Is my perspective math correct?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/is-my-perspective-math-correct)

This question was asked in November, has received 19 upvotes and been favorited 2 times, and a comment even says *"+1 for showing that homework questions can be high-quality questions."*, yet it doesn't have a single answer. I've myself stopped by it a few times, but never had the motivation to go all the way through the exercise.

What should we do about it? Does it mean even good homework question aren't a good fit?

Comment: It certainly would be good to see this answered, particularly as that would show our site in a better light to newcomers. I know this isn't as good as an actual solution, but I've added a bounty.

Comment: The problem is that its made with matlab, i dont currently have matlab so i can not fix it even if i wanted to. All matlab questions get a long wait time on this site. We just dont seem to attract matlab users.

Comment: This now has an [answer](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/3948/231) :)

Comment: @trichoplax: yes, and a very good one at it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting a [bounty](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) is always a good way to promote well-asked, but unanswered questions.

See also: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

> First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on any question more than two days old.